# Text input gets unfocused after typing one character in input field React?

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to react so bare with me, in the upcoming code every time i try to input something in the ***input field*** i only get to type one letter then an ***unfoucs*** happens automatically i have already done some research online but the solutions i found did not match my case ***!!!***

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";
import WeatherCard from "./components/WeatherCard/component";

function App() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("Sydney,AU");
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState("");
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");

  const data = async () => {
    const apiRes = await fetch(
      `
      https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&APPID=fc3c4a92fca29f784461262f448883f4
      `
    );
    const resJSON = await apiRes.json();
    return resJSON;
  };

  const Frame = styled.div`
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: whitesmoke;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  `;

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    data().then((res) => {
      console.log("the weather feels like" + res.main.feels_like);
      console.log("the temp is " + res.main.temp);
      setTemp(res.main.temp);
    });
  };
  return (
    <Frame>
      <WeatherCard temp={temp} condition="Clear" city="Sydney" country="AU" />
      <form>
        <input value={city} onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={(e) => handleSearch(e)}>Search</button>
      </form>
    </Frame>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured out the problem, it was in this part of the code ***:***

```
  const Frame = styled.div`
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: whitesmoke;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  `;
```

all i had to do was to delete the styling from this file and i added the styling in ***app.css*** instead
and i converted the ***Frame*** tag to a ***div*** tag with the className of frame,
so basically the problem was in the way of styling the Component.